# SignalR 2 hub is not deployed with ASP MVC 5 web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which references another project, that is a SignalR application. The web makes occasional calls of the SignalR app. I have deployed the web a while ago on a Microsoft Azure server. The deployment included also the SignalR hub, which was available via mysite.azurewebsites.net/signalr/hubs.

Now, I have made some updates in the web application and wanted to re-upload the whole solution again. However, I cannot manage to deploy both projects at the same time. I can either deploy the SignalR hub, or the web application, but the mysite.azurewebsites.net/signalr/hubs does not find any hubs.

At first I have thought it was caused by the routing change in ASP MVC app. I have changed

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        )
```

to

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

But even after reverting the changes, I cannot deploy both applications at the same time. I don't understand, where the problem might be.

One big change that I have made is adding the ASP.NET Identity package to my website. The package also uses the OWIN library (similar to SignalR). Could this be the problem? I hope not, because then I would have to re-do the whole database again...

**EDIT**

I have tried moving the Startup class into the ASP.MVC application:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyMvcApp.Startup))]
namespace MyMvcApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to locate any hubs outside the current assembly.

Comment: When you deploy, are you deploying them separately? Or does your MVC app reference your SignalR project?

Comment: Yes, the MVC app references the SignalR hub project/dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have overridden the startup in Web.config:

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyMvcApp.IdentityConfig" />
```

Removing this line and moving the code from `IdentityConfig.cs` to `Startup.cs` solved the problem.